# Moving average model, MA(q) implementation

Tags: finance, time-series

Assuming that I have a Time Series 'X'
which is a 1000 days data of a stock.

can someone share a code sample (in any language)
even pseudo code for the Moving average model order q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example in Matlab for MA(2)
the problem that I was engaging with is how to get the models parameters (0.2,0.5).

```
X = zeros(10000,1);
Z = randn(10000,1);

for i=3:length(X)
    X(i) = Z(i) + 0.5*Z(i-1) + 0.2*Z(i-2); 
end 

plot(X)
```

I did some more research and I understand that the parameters are sent as an input which is selected manually or by an optimization process.
so this the same works for Moving average order q.

Comment: The values $X(1)$ and $X(2)$ can be calculated using $X(1)=Z(1)$ and $X(2)=Z(2)+0.5Z(1)$. The $\mathrm{MA}(2)$ starts from $X(3)$ as you did.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about your purpose but if you just want to calibrate the model, use R.
i.p
require(smooth)
require(MComp)
sma(data,q)$forecast

Comment: I purpose is for studying, and that's why I have to implement it.
And I meant the Moving average Model, not the Simple Moving average.
[See Example in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model)

Answer (score -1):

Again an R Code:

weights<-rep(1/q,q) # or any desired weights 
 ma<-filter(data,weights,sides=1)

plot(data) 
 lines(ma)

and you can also take a look at the autocorrelation function 
 acf(ma,na.action=na.pass)